# Is there a meaningful design decision behind Rust's static compiling be default?

Tags: rust, plugins, dynamic-loading

I am exploring the option to dynamically load libraries at runtime in Rust.  I am still a Rust newbie, so I found several articles detailing why this is not the recommended way.

1. [Plugins in Rust](https://nullderef.com/blog/plugin-start/)
2. [Dynamically Loading Plugin](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/creating-rust-apps-with-dynamically-loaded-rust-plugins/28814)
3. [Rust has no stable ABI](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/abefuy/comment/ed02ajs/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)

I have not found, or maybe have not fully understood why this is so?  Rust is a systems programming language to my understanding, and such, isn't dynamic loading and plugin writing important to this goal?

Is there a meaningful design decision behind Rust's static compiling be default?

As a side note: I have found a [crate](https://docs.rs/abi_stable/latest/abi_stable/) that supports this pretty well, but before using it I would like to understand why the Rust creators would rather not build this into the language.

Comment: Re: built into language or not, committing things to the language (or library) is hard to undo. Rust prefers to leave things to crates if it can, that way there is no need to rush things. (Unlike, say,  C++ which is a disaster in part because it has no package manager, and the only way to get anything done is to shoehorn it into the standard library, which is then promptly used by nobody.) Of all the things to commit to, a fixed ABI is _the_ most difficult thing to change. Rust uses C as the stable ABI for this reason, and that is the way to go about this for now.

Comment: Note that when you are compiling a Rust executable along with dependant crates, the compiler makes memory safety guarantees that are enforced for all compiled code. For example, allocation and freeing of memory are guaranteed to use one global allocator. Now imagine a dynamic library is compiled with a custom global allocator. If some object is allocated within the main program, but freed in a dynamic library through change of ownership via a move, what guarantee do we have that it will be safely deallocated? See https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/alloc/index.html

Comment: @GManNickG notice that C don't have any official ABI so your sentence are quite ironic.

Comment: @SirDarius This is as close to answer as I am going to get on this I believe.  would you consider making this an answer?

Comment: I wouldn't say that my comment is an exhaustive answer. It merely revolves around a specific aspect that came to mind. I invite you to research the topic thoroughly and publish my comment as part of an answer yourself :-)